# Non-zero Conditional Differential Entropy between a random variable and a function of it

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy

Let two *continuous* random variables, where the one is a function of the other: $X\,  $ and $\,  Y=g\left(X\right)$. Their *mutual information* is defined as
$$I\left(X,Y\right)\,=\,h\left(X\right)\,-\,h\left(X|Y\right)=\,h\left(Y\right)\,-\,h\left(Y|X\right)$$
where lowercase *h* denotes *differential* entropy, the entropy concept for continuous rv's. It is a proven fact that the mutual information *between two variables*, for discrete as well as for continuous rv's, is non-negative, and becomes zero only when the two rv's are independent (clearly not our case).
Using the fact that Y is a function of X we have
$$I\left(X,g\left(X\right)\right)\,=\,h\left(g\left(X\right)\right)\,-\,h\left(g\left(X\right)|X\right) \gt\,0\,\Rightarrow \,h\left(g\left(X\right)\right)\,\gt \,h\left(g\left(X\right)|X\right)$$
Now, differential entropy (unlike entropy for discrete rv's) can take negative values.
Assume that it so happens that $h\left(g\left(X\right)\right)\lt\,0$. Then from the positivity of mutual information we obtain
$$0\,\gt \,h\left(g\left(X\right)\right)\,\gt \,h\left(g\left(X\right)|X\right) \Rightarrow\; h\left(g\left(X\right)|X\right)\neq\,0$$
***And this is the counter-intuitive puzzle***: for any discrete random variable *Z* we always have $h\left(g\left(Z\right)|Z\right)\,=\,0$. This is intuitive: if *Z* is known, then any function of *Z* is completely determined -no entropy, no uncertainty remains, and so the conditional entropy measure is zero. But we just saw that, when dealing with continuous rv's where the one is a function of the other, their conditional differential entropy may be non-zero (it doesn't matter whether it is positive or negative), which is not intuitive at all. Because, even in this strange world of continuous rv's, knowing *X*, completely determines *Y=g(X)*. I have searched high and low to find any discussion, comment or exposition of the matter, but I found nothing. Cover & Thomas book does not mention it, other books do not mention it, a myriad of scientific papers or web sites do not mention it.

***My motives:*** a) Scientific curiosity. b) I want to use the concept of mutual information for continuous rv's in an econometrics paper I am writing, and I feel very uncomfortable to just mention the "non-zero conditional differential entropy" case without being able to discuss it a bit. So any intuition, reference, suggestion, idea, or full answer of course, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Although conditional differential entropy changes, MI does not change for invertible transformations, and is well defined. If you want more interpretable entropies for continuous variables, perhaps you should look into *relative entropy*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it... although the symmetric nature of MI is much more appealing. Still, it is strange that I couldn't find any mention of the case I presented in my question.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I think it returns to the question that why differential entropy is called differential entropy! I remember our professor told us the answer of your question, but unfortunately I don't remember the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paradox can be stated in a simpler form:

We know that $I(X;Y)=h(X)-h(X|Y)\ge 0$ holds, also for continuous variables. Consider the particular case $Y=X$. Then the second term vanishes: $h(X|X)=0$, and we get

$$ I(X;X)= h(X)-h(X|X)=h(X) \ge 0$$

But cannot be right. The differential entropy can be negative.  So what?

> when dealing with continuous rv's where the one is a function of the
> other, **their conditional differential entropy may be non-zero** (it
> doesn't matter whether it is positive or negative), which is not
> intuitive at all.

Your problem (and the problem with the above paradox) is to implicitly assume that the concept "*zero entropy means no uncertainty*" applies also to differential entropy. That's false. The differential entropy is not some type of entropy. It's false that $h(g(X)|X)=0$, it's false that $h(X|X)=0$; and it's false that $h(X)=0$ implies zero uncertainty. The fact that (by a mere change of scale) a differential entropy can be made negative, suggests by itself that here zero differential entropy (conditional or not) has no special meaning. In particular, a uniform variable in $[0,1]$ has $h(X)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much  for reaching back two years. I will read your answer carefully (I am very much still interested in the matter), and maybe I will have a question or two in order to understand it fully.

Answer (score 4):

Differential entropy is only defined for absolutely continuous random variables with respect to Lebesgue measure. The joint distribution of

$$(X,g(X))$$

is not absolutely continuous because its support is

$$\{(x,g(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\},$$

a measure 0 subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The definition of conditional entropy requires an absolutely continuous joint distribution, $f(x,y)$: 
\begin{align} h(X|Y) &= -\int f(x,y) \log f(x|y)\ dxdy \\
                &= h(X,Y)-h(Y).
\end{align}
If $(X,Y)$ is not absolutely continuous against Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there is no function $f(x,y)$ such that the probability measure of $(X,Y)$ can be expressed as an integral against $f$.

Therefore neither the quantity $h(g(X)|X)$, nor the quantity $I(X;g(X))$ are well defined as differential entropies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand¨correctly, in naive terms, because $g(X)$ is a _function_, it follows that the joint support will be a line and not an area in $\mathbb R^2$, which makes it of measure 0, as discussed here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944241/87400 and here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145820/87400 ?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes. And the measure 0 support means that the joint variable does not have a pdf.