# Conditional entropy under quantization

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and $X^n$ its quantization that becomes finer with larger $n$. Let $Y$ be a deterministic function of $X$. Then we have that the conditional entropy
$$H(Y|X) = 0$$
because $Y$ is a function of $X$.

Furthermore, we have $H(Y|X^n) = \infty$ for all $n$ because the distribution of $Y|X^n = x^n$ is continuous.

Now my question is, is it valid to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} H(Y|X^n) = H(Y|X)$? Intuitively, I would say it is, but it seems impossible to construct an ($\epsilon$-$\delta$) proof for this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The differential entropy is not the entropy. Your first assertion (if $H$ is a differential entropy) is false. See eg http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1398471/312 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454078/non-zero-conditional-differential-entropy-between-a-random-variable-and-a-functi

Comment: I don't consider differential entropy here. Since $Y$ is known for a given $X = x$, $H(Y|X = x) = 0$ and then also $H(Y|X) = 0$, right?

Comment: I don't understand how you define the entropy of a continuous variable ($Y$) if it's not the differential entropy.

Comment: Ok, so I agree that for continuous variables there is differential entropy (denote it with $h(Y)$). In most cases $h(Y) < \infty$ and $H(Y) = \infty$ (where $H(Y)$ is normal entropy). But now, since $Y$ is a function of $X$, the distribution of $Y|X=x$ is no longer continuous but discrete, or am I totally wrong here? Then $H(Y|X) = \int_{\mathcal X} H(Y|X=x) \text{d}P_X(x) = 0$.

Comment: Then you must use different definitions for the two entropies. The "infinite" entropy $H(Y|X^n) = \infty$ can only make sense if defined as a limit. Then, you have two iterated limits, and your assertion is ambiguous. Take as an example $Y=X$ and $X$ uniform in $[0,a]$

Comment: To make sense of your paradox, I suggest you work out this simpler one. Consider $X_n$ uniform in $[0,1/n]$, $n=1,2, \cdots$ Then $H(X_n)=+\infty$ for all $n$. Now, consider a discrete variable $X$ taking the single value $0$ (a constant), hence $H(X)=0$. It's true (... in some sense) that $X_n \to X$ as $n\to \infty$ , But it's false that $H(X_n) \to H(X)$

Comment: So $\lim_{n \to \infty} H(X_n)$ just doesn't exist?

Comment: Either does not exists, or it's infinite. But it's not zero. In general, if $g(n)>M$ $\forall n$, then it cannot happen that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)< M$

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @leonbloy: Even if $Y$ is continuous, since $Y=f(X)$, the statement $H(Y|X)=0$ is correct and meaningful.

Comment: @Bernhard What is $H(Y|X)$ when $Y$ is continuous? It's a differential entropy or not? How do you define it?

Comment: @leonbloy: $Y$ is continuous, but $Y|X=x$ is not. You define it simply as $H(Y|X)=\int_\Omega H(Y|X=x) dP_X(x)$. It is not a differential entropy, but a Shannon entropy. Note that the conditional differential entropy $h(Y|X)=-\infty$.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm ok with that. But, then, the (Shannon) entropy  $H(Y|X=x) $ with $Y$ continuous is $+\infty$ unless the density consists of Dirac deltas (i.e. unless $Y$ is discrete - informally speaking).

Comment: @leonbloy: If $Y=g(X)$, then $Y$ is not continuous given that $X=x$. In other words, if $Y=g(X)$,. then, informally speaking, the density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $\delta(y-g(x))$. The RV $Y|X=x$ is discrete, with a single mass point at $y=g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution of $Y|X^n=x$ converges to the probability distribution $Y|X=x$ for increasing $n$. Nevertheless, and that is the problem in this case, entropy is not continuous in a converging sequence of probability measures (see, e.g., [this paper](http://iest2.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~whyeung/tempo/discon2.pdf)).