# Mutual information of continuous variables

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I think I am misunderstanding the notion of mutual information of continuous variables. Could anyone help me clear up the following?

Let $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $ and $Y \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $ denote Gaussian random variables. If $X$ and $Y$ are correlated with a coefficient $\rho$, then the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ is given by
(reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

\begin{equation}
I(X; Y) = -\frac{1}{2} \log (1-\rho^2).
\end{equation}

Here, I thought $I(X; Y) \rightarrow \infty$ when $\rho \rightarrow 1$ (for $X = Y$, $\rho = 1$). I considered this another way.

I considered $Y = X$.
In this case, I would obtain $ I (X; Y) = H(X) - H(Y|X) = H(X) $.

For the Gaussian random variable $X$, $H(X)$ is bounded as follows (reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy):
\begin{equation}
H(X) \leq \frac{1}{2} \log ( 2 \pi e \sigma^2).
\end{equation}

Thus, $ I (X; Y) \leq \frac{1}{2} \log ( 2 \pi e \sigma^2)$.

Here is my question.
I obtained two different results on $ I (X; Y)$ for $X = Y$.
What could be some mistakes in my understanding?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One usually writes $h(X)$ for the differetial entropy, not $H(X)$, and with good reason, it reminds you that it's not a "true" entropy, so that you don't into the trap of assuming $h(X |X)=0$ (as with the true entropy). Actually $h(X|X)=-\infty$. See eg my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540731/neural-networks-data-processing-inequality-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differential entropy can actually be negative, and thus the upper bound on your information is not correct. Indeed, if they are the same random variable on a continuous domain, then you would hope that the mutual information between them would be infinite (and if they are the same Gaussian, indeed that is the case).

EDIT: I guess I should have clarified: In differential entropy sense, H(Y | X) is not 0; it is negative infinity if X = Y. Any singularity in differential entropy has negative infinite relative uncertainty to any quantized uniform distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
However, the upper bound ($H(X) \leq \frac{1}{2} \log ( 2 \pi e \sigma^2 )$) is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy.
Also, $ -\frac{1}{2} \log ( 1 - \rho^2 ) $ is based on this formular.

Comment: See edit above; I realized I did not actually write the negative quantity.

Comment: Okay, I got your point.
So my assumption on $H ( Y | X ) = 0 $ only holds when $X$ and $Y$ are discrete and $Y=X$.
In case of continuous R.Vs, $H ( Y | X ) = - \infty $ for $Y=X$.
Thus, $ I(X; Y) = H(X) - (-\infty) = \infty $ for $X=Y$.
Thank you!

Comment: @InkyuBang Your  assumption on $H(X|X)=0$ only holds for the true (Shannon) entropy. It does not apply to differential entropy, which is a different beast. The (true/Shannon) entropy of a (non degenerate) continuous variable is $+\infty$, because (among other things) you need (on average) an infinite amount of bits to represent its value.