# $H(Y|X)=0$ if $Y=f(X)$ where $f$ is deterministic and $X$ is a continuous r.v.

Tags: conditional-probability

I'd like to show that the conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ is zero when $Y$ is deterministically determined by $X$ (i.e., $Y=f(X)$) and $X$ is *continuous* random variable.

This claim is easy to prove when $X$ is a discrete r.v., but I feel kind of clueless for continuous r.v. $X$.

Should I approach with Dirac delta function? I can have the below
$$
H(Y|X) = \int_x p(x) \int_y p(y|x) \log p(y|x) dydx 
= \int_x p(x) \int_y \delta_{f(x)}(y) \log \delta_{f(x)}(y) dy dx
$$
But from here, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of stuff going on here.

---

First: the entropy definition for discrete rv's does not apply for continuous rv's. Instead, you can use the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) $h(X)$ which is defined for continuous r.v.'s:
$$h(X)=-\int_{\mathcal{X}}f_X(x)\log\big(f_X(x)\big)\,dx\,,$$
with $\mathcal{X}$ being the support of $X$ and $f_X(x)$ the PDF of $X$.

In the same way, the [differential conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Conditional_differential_entropy) $h(Y|X)$ is given by
$$h(X|Y)=-\int_{\mathcal{X,Y}}f_{XY}(x,y)\log\big(f_{X|Y}(x|y)\big)\,dxdy=h(X,Y)-h(Y)$$
with the corresponding definitions of support, joint PDF and conditional PDF. These are also used to define mutual information of continuous r.v.'s.

Also, note that differential entropy can be negative (because PDFs can be larger than 1), and that varies with scale.

---

Second, the conditional differential entropy $h(g(X)|X)$ is **not** necessarily zero. Thus, the statement you are trying to prove is not true.  See [this MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454078/non-zero-conditional-differential-entropy-between-a-random-variable-and-a-functi) question for a better exposition and discussion. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, in fact I was using the definition of differntial entropy. I plausibly derived that the conditional entropy is negative infitnie, but not really sure my approah is correct. Anyhow, thanks for the link!

Comment: One of the observations in the answers to the other question is that differential entropy is scale variant, and so, depending on the support of $X$ for a particular scale, the differential entropy might take different values. But as the other answer states, $h(g(X)
|X)$ might not even be defined.