# Lebesgue outer measure of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is zero

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Following [Lebesgue measure of any line in $\mathbb{R^2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944241/lebesgue-measure-of-any-line-in-mathbbr2) I want to show that the lebesgue outer measure of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is zero.

Does the following constitue a good way to show this fact?

Take $R_n = [n - \dfrac{1}{2} , n + \dfrac{1}{2} ] \times [-\epsilon/2^n, \epsilon/2^n], n \in \mathbb{Z}$

This is a cover of $\mathbb{R}$

$\sum_n |R_n| = 2\epsilon$, then $\mu^*(\mathbb{R}) = 0$

Correctomundo?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdK6sR5Sfdc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes.

1. Usually, an open cover is used.
2. Remember the nagatives. You need $2^{-|n|}$ if $n$ is negative.

Therefore, 
 I'd replace your expression for $R_n$  by $(n-1,n+1)\times \epsilon (-2^{-|n|},2^{-|n|})$. This has measure $4\epsilon 2^{-|n|}$. Now sum.